# TDA7297 amplifier board gives no sound

Tags: amplifier, audio

I have a small, simple circuit here. It doesn't work - both outputs (left and right side) are mute.

It uses the TDA7297 chip, and outputs 2 x 15W. I've wired 12V to '12V', and GND to -12V. I'm beginning to think that's the problem. Speakers need negative voltages as well... I've got a few LM337s laying around, should one of these be used to provide -12V?

[image: Annoying circuit]

[image: Chip pinout]

[image: Asian sensation]

If you need additional info, tell me.

Comment: Can you trace the tracks on the PC board to see where the "-12V" terminal connects?  I suspect that it connects to GND, and to the TDA7297's Power Ground on Pin 8, whch should also connect to the Signal Ground on pin 9.  If so, you should apply 12 volts between the "+12V" and "-12V" terminals. the ST-By and MUTE terminal should be pulled high, as shown in Fig 3 of the datasheet.

Comment: It does indeed connect to GND. Then my circuit shouldn't be broken.

Comment: The only mystery bit is the 'JX' jump behind the two caps. It did not work without it, and it did not work with it. There has not even been a faint sound from the three different speakers I have tried, and everything seems correctly wired.

Comment: @user400344 - Re: "The only mystery bit is the 'JX' jump behind the two caps. It did not work without it, and it did not work with it." Readers can't answer that question without having the PCB in their hands to trace it (or having good photos of the trace side), so it's best for *you* to identify the points in the circuit which can be linked by jumper "JX". Then once you have reported those points here, readers can help identify the function of "JX" from the [TDA7297 datasheet](http://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/tda7297.pdf). Personally I would just trace the entire circuit from the PCB.

Comment: @SamGibson Will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the info - the chip was bad. Used a TDA7296 ( http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/3a/2f/b7/86/30/b2/4b/6c/CD00000198.pdf/files/CD00000198.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00000198.pdf ) to replace it. It seems to work fine for the moment.

All the answers and comments were appreciated.

Comment: Will accept my own answer in 14 hours as SE has some control mechanism in place.

Comment: It would make much more sense to accept @user49628's answer, since he very well explained *why* the TDA7297 chip became bad. And you can also guess from his explanations why it would now work with a TDA7296 (since this part can accept +/-35V).

Comment: That's not why the chip became bad. Even at first when I fed it 3V and 5V with an audio signal entering the circuit, there was no movement of the speaker membranes. -12V was equivalent electrically to GND on the PCB. I fed the TDA7297 with 12V, just like I do the TDA7296. I can now achieve 2 x 30W. His answer was informative, of course.

Comment: "WIDE SUPPLY VOLTAGE RANGE (6V -18V)".  3V and 5V was too little, 24V was too much.  I find it less likely that the part you bought was sold defective.

Answer (score 9):

The TDA7297 is specified for a single supply, up to 18V. So, it seems your mistake was connecting GND to -12V. It should be connected to ground - that is, the return of your +12V supply.

Because this chip drives the output in a bridge configuration, the differential output signal can go positive and negative with only a positive supply.

It's likely that you damaged the chip by supplying it with 24V when the specified absmax is 20V. You'll want to swap it out before trying again.

Comment: @user400344 This. The speakers don't need a negative voltage relative to "ground"; they just need their inputs to vary with respect to each other.  And this is what the TDA7297 does.

Comment: There was no magic smoke, and I still detect electromagnetic field on all parts of the circuit (this is a valid debugging approach). If it's baked, I've got 2 x TDA7296 chips here. What's the point of -12V on the PCB? Should I just connect GND of both audio input and 12V together? It's not that I don't enjoy a bit of fireworks, but I'm a careful audio-virgin.

Comment: Connecting GND of both the audio input and the 12V supply should cause no problem, provided the input signal is AC coupled as shown in the datasheet application schematic. As to why there is a pin labeled -12V on your PCB, I can't comment. Seems pretty weird though - is it the kind of cheapo PCB assembly you see on ebay, etc? I have certainly seen gross errors on those types of assemblies ranging from labeling and documentation to basic design...

Answer (score 3):

Are you putting both ST-BY and MUTE to a logic high as described in the data sheet?  The TDA7297 won't give any output unless you do:

[image: Mute Timing]

You can just tie them high with a couple of resistors if you don't want to control them:
[image: Enable Amplifier]

Comment: Yes I am doing that.

Comment: Rather, I'm using two 47K resistors. I assumed they did that, but will look at it again tomorrow. Thanks for the clue.

Comment: Added 47K pull-ups from pin 6+7 to VCC. It makes no difference. Will try a different chip and audio source tomorrow.

Answer (score -2):

I have exactly this kit, and just traced out the PCB to find out how it was wired. The JX link is between pin 3 and 13 of the TDA7297, so it is providing the Vcc +12V to pin 13 (amplifier 2).

The circuit is the one partially shown in Kevin White's answer, above: i.e. this is the low-cost application example from page 5 of the chip datasheet, except that the 100nF cap has been omitted, and additionally there is a protection diode in the +12V line.

Comment: This looks more like a couple of comments to me.  What makes this an answer?

Comment: Ok. Make sure to add value yourself.